# Office 365 SharePoint, can you script (powershell) or code provisioning of the site?

Tags: powershell, office-365

I am trying to figure out if you can use Powershell with Commandlets to provision a new site.
Basically if a customer calls for our solution can I write  script that sets it all up?
(Creating the site structure, lists, forms, documents?). I have looked through the cmdlets I could find and related to Office365 and I could not find any that deals with creating sites, creating lists etc.

I presume if that does not exist that the way to go is Visual Studio and a sandboxed SharePoint solution? That should give us most of the freedom we need?

Is there a way to migrate from an existing in house SharePoint solution and "upgrade" it to Office 365 in the cloud? Does one need a 3rd party product? Like MetaLogix?

Comment: ->I suppose there was an error during the migration. This should belong to the main site, not Meta.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Yeh, I flagged this yesterday. It seems Meta isn't very moderated at the moment...

Comment: Actually, I also had flagged this - I left the comment only to be sure. I'm starting to think that all the mods are busy helping Santa Jeff to fill his sleigh with gifts for all the developers working with SharePoint all around the world.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no Windows PowerShell commandlets that allow you to create new SharePoint Site Collections in Office 365.  That has to be done manually.

However, once you have a site created you can upload a WSP that provisions all your lists etc... that you want in the site.

You can also use the Client Side OM to upload the WSP, however to "Activate" it you need to do this in the UI manually.

Alternatively you can use the CSOM to create your lists and libraries etc... however using a WSP will work out better for you in the long run with things like upgrade down the track.

Answer (score 0):

You can create feature and add a feature event receiver and in FeatureActivated event you could write code that sets it all up and in FeatureDeactivating event write code code that clean it all. [Adding a Feature Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620533)